# New Users not showing up for File Permissions on Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012, asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of setting up Web Deploy for a MVC4 (ASP.NET) application.

Whilst setting up my users on the Windows Server 2012 interface, my users are not showing up in the list for access permissions.

Has anyone had the same problem?  What is the solution?

Comment: Just to clarify... Where are you setting up the users and where are you trying to to set the access permissions?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by users not showing up in a list? IIS users? Windows users, NTFS permissions?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: They are windows users and trying to give them full access permission on the directory their web files are stored, I can do it all as administrator, but need other accounts rather than giving all user administrator access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never had the problem, but the solution is, just to type the name of the user and click the 'Check Names' button to verify that you spelled the name correctly. Also make sure that 'Users' appears in the 'Select the object type:' field of the dialog.

General recommendations:

- Use groups rather than users when assigning NTFS permissions.
- Use icacls.exe to set permissions, put the commands in a batch file.
  This    works as documentation and can also be used for other sites
  or    servers.